# Switching between Tkinter screens with withdraw() method on button click

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-button

Everything here works just fine but I haven't found a way to make it so that when I press the start button   it withdraws the Main Menu screen and displays the next one. It already creates the second screen when I run the code and it withdraws the MainMenu Screen before I even click the start button.

https://replit.com/@AbdullahKaran/ConfusedSophisticatedFolders#main.py

Comment: Please don't link to code on another site. Paste and format the code directly in your question.

Comment: Used `tk.tk()` for entire script. This should be inside `click` function and replace the `ChapterOne1stScreen =tk.Tk()` with `ChapterOne1stScreen =tk.Toplevell()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you can do this by using the `tkraise()` method of the `Frame` widget. To learn more, please visit this website: https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkraise/